# JavaScript switch turns

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to do a function for checkers and where it tells the person whose turn it is.

JavaScript

```
function getCurrentPlayerColor(){
// if even number of moves in moves array, it's black's turn, otherwise red's


   return moves.length % 2 === 0 ? "r" : "b";
}
```

I want to use this function when it is black turn

```
 document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Blacks Turn";
```

and this function when its red turn

```
document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Reds Turn";
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Even shorter: `return ["r", "b"][moves.length % 2];` This creates an array of options and selects one based on the index passed in by the modulus. It also lets you expand on the number of players programmatically by using more letters. Ie. `var players = ["r", "b", "g"]; return players[moves.length % players.length];`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're halfway there - you've got a function to check whose turn it is, so you can just use it like this:

```
if (getCurrentPlayerColor() === "r") {
    document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Red's Turn";
} else {
    document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = "Black's Turn";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCurrentPlayerColor(){
// if even number of moves in moves array, it's black's turn, otherwise red's
   document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = (moves.length % 2 ? 'Blacks' : 'Reds') + ' Turn'
}
```

or

```
function getCurrentPlayerColor(){
// if even number of moves in moves array, it's black's turn, otherwise red's
   return moves.length % 2 === 0 ? "r" : "b";
}

document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = (getCurrentPlayerColor() === 'r' ? 'Reds' : 'Blacks') + ' Turn'
```

plus

`document.getElementById("turn")` is qeual to `turn` variable so we can do it in shorter

```
turn.innerHTML = (moves.length % 2 ? 'Blacks' : 'Reds') + ' Turn'
```